# unable to append object to List<T> in realm using swift

Tags: swift, object, realm

so I have two objects like the following :

```
class BankModel: Object {

    dynamic var bankModelId: String = ""
    dynamic var bankName: String!
    dynamic var bankBranch: String?

    var coordinate: List<LocationModel>!

    dynamic var buyingTWD: String?
    dynamic var buyingUSD: String?
    dynamic var sellingTHB: String?
    dynamic var sellingUSD: String?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "bankModelId"
    }
}
```

and

```
class LocationModel: Object {

    dynamic var locationId: String = ""
    dynamic var latitude: String = ""
    dynamic var longitude: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "locationId"
    }
}
```

when I try to append LocationModel

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let bankModel = BankModel()
let coordinate = LocationModel()
coordinate.locationId = "1"
coordinate.longitude = "20.11111"
coordinate.latitude = "123.21412"
bankModel.bankModelId = "1"
bankModel.bankName = "SuperRich Orange"
bankModel.bankBranch = "HQ"
bankModel.buyingUSD = "\(buyingUSDRepalced)"
bankModel.buyingTWD = "\(buyingTWDRepalced)"
bankModel.coordinate.append(coordinate)

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(bankModel, update: true)
}
```

I got this fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

No clue why is this happening, any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `coordinate` is `nil`. You haven't initialized it. The compiler doesn't complain because you declared it as an [implictly unwrapped optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362131/7347933), which can be `nil`. Use

```
var coordinate = List<LocationModel>()
```

instead.